# Pylons: Set global variable for Authkit user

Tags: python, pylons, authkit

How can I can set a global variable for the username of the logged-in user? At the moment i have the following code in all my controllers to get the username. I rather set it as a global variable if possible.

`request.environ.get("REMOTE_USER")`

I tried putting the same code in the app_globals.py file but it gave me the following error message: 
"No object (name: request) has been registered for this thread"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single "logged-in user" if you're serving requests on multiple threads -- by setting a single global variable the threads would trample upon each other and end up very very confused on who "the logged-in user" actually *is*.  There **is** (at most;-) a single logged-in user **per request**, so keeping that info in the request object seems vastly preferable;-).